# Email trigger for google sheet when a specific column is updated to "YES" and Email id's to be taken from another column in the same sheet

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have multiple rows and columns which will be updated on a daily basis, and I want email to be triggered to mail id's taken from another column from the same sheet.

For example I have many email id's present in column C [can't mention a specific range since the data will be added everyday] and when values of column H are marked "Yes" then the mail id from the corresponding row in C column must be taken and email should be triggered to that id. I have tried multiple scripts but it's not working.

Comment: There are no such triggers. Unless the changes occur due to user edits and in that case you could use [onEdit()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit)

Comment: Is it possible to just send an email notification when the user edits the value to "YES"?  Where the email id is taken from another column to send an email? @Cooper

Comment: What's the email Id?

Comment: I have multiple email id's, I have stored the same in column B of the same sheet, When a change is made to column H, The email should be sent to concerned mail id which is stored in the corresponding row.

Comment: I'm just not familiar with what an Email Id is.  What do you do with it? How is it used?

Comment: For example, Column B has email address of the different employees in different rows who are waiting for few changes to be made on a project, Column H should be updated by the dev team after the changes are made. Hence when column H is updated with an entry "YES", The Corresponding employee's email address present in the Column B should receive an email notification.

Answer (score 1):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if(e.range.getSheet().getName()!='Sheet Name Used in this Operation') return;
  if(e.range.columnStart==8 && e.value=="YES") {
    //Send email
  } 
}
```

I'm not sure but I think you may need to create an installable trigger to send email.

Comment: I have tried the above code but throws an exception on line 2

Comment: I hope you realize you can’t run it from the code editor.  I would set it up in a sample spreadsheet and get it to working by just using it because you need to generate an onEdit() trigger. And of course you need to add the send email code.

Answer (score 1):

#### Enable the Gmail service for your script

1. Go to your sheet and click Tools > Script editor
2. In the script editor, click Resources > Advanced Google Services... enable 'Gmail API' and click OK

#### Code

Copy & paste the following code (and make any modifications, if needed) to your sheet's script editor:

```js
function sendEmail(dest, data) {
  var messageBody = 'Hello, there has been a new release:\n\n' + JSON.stringify(data);
  GmailApp.sendEmail(dest, 'Automated email from sheet', messageBody);
}

function onEditTrigger(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  if (range.columnStart == 8 && e.value == 'YES') {
    // Prepare the email
    var row = range.getSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, 8).getValues()[0];
    var headers = range.getSheet().getRange(1, 1, 1, 8).getValues()[0];

    var dest = row[1];
    var data = {};
    for (var i=0; i<8; i++) {
      data[headers[i]] = row[i];
    }

    sendEmail(dest, data);
  }
}
```

The code will get the 8 first columns of the row that has been modified and send them to the email specified in column B, along with the headers, as JSON format. You can see the spreadsheet I used for testing [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1e84ce1vgaMqcoI3cMXAH92Zea7yTDPMAOLSwIrOfmvU/edit?usp=sharing). The email I received looks like the following:

[image]

#### Set the onEditTrigger function as an installable trigger

1. From the sheet's script editor, click the clock icon ("*Current project's triggers*")
2. Click the *Add Trigger* button
3. Choose the *onEditTrigger* function as the function to be ran, and *On edit* as the event type ([example trigger configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3a5A.png)) and click save

Now every time the sheet gets modified the code above will run, and if appropriate, send the message.

Comment: Hey Carlesgg97, Thanks for answer, The code works but when I try to add an "else if" it throws an error.  I am pasting a sample [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LRN-fp5fb8TNRc1fUszBjn0ZKpuTMT5AsIBjK4skc8A/edit?usp=sharing) where we would use the modified scenario, I want to check column "G" for Yes/No, If <Yes> It should take the mail address from column "C" and send the mail. If <no> then it should again send the email taking the address from column "C" but it should also include messages from column "J". I am trying to write an else if but throws multiple errors.